# Remove a portion of String after certain value

Tags: string, for-loop, batch-file, delete-row, find-replace

I am using below mentioned code for finding a string in a file(Constants.TcGVL), assign my desired value(%select%) to it and copy to a new location:

```
Call :ValueSubstitude "%root%\LeafSpring\Constants.TcGVL"  "%root%\LeafSpring\GVLs\Constants.TcGVL" "%select%"
```

```
:ValueSubstitude
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Set "Tag1=nNrOfInstances : UINT := " 
Set "Tag2=%~3"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%~1) do ( 
Set "str=%%a"
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set str=!str:%Tag1%=%Tag1%%Tag2%!
echo !str!>>"%~2"
ENDLOCAL
)
Exit /B 0
```

Original file has string like this:
`nNrOfInstances : UINT := 3;`

Now my %select% value could be 1, 2 ,3...and I want to replace '3' in above line with my desired number but the output I am getting is wrong.

The output looks like this:

`=nNrOfInstances : UINT := 1= 3;`

It has a space and equal sign at start of line and = 3 at the end. It has my desire number in it which is 1 but also the earlier value = 3 which should not be there.

Kindly assist me getting the right output or let me know what am I doing wrong here.
Thank you.

Comment: We expect a [mcve]. That includes telling us exactly what the arguments `%1`, `%2`, and `%3` are, and exactly how those are passed to the batch file or `:ValueSubstitude` label.You should also provide a little information about the file, _(assumed to be, `%1`)_; for instance its data type, encoding and line ending details.

Comment: String replacement within variable expansion will not allow you to replace an equal symbol which is why you are getting said output.

Comment: I think the best you could without using a third party utility would be `if "!str:~0,23!"=="nNrOfInstances : UINT :" (>>"%~2" echo nNrOfInstances : UINT : %Tag2%) else (>>"%~2" echo !str!)`

Comment: your problem is likely arising from the fact that the `=` sign cannot be replaced using substring modification. one solution would be to use a `For /f` loop to split the returned string using the options `tokens=1,2* delims==`

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "tag2=2"
Set "Tag1=nNrOfInstances : UINT := " 
for /f "delims=" %%e in (q77984148.txt) do (
 ECHO %%e|FINDSTR /b /L /c:"%tag1%" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %%e) ELSE (
 ECHO %tag1%%tag2%;)
)
```

I used a file named `q77984148.txt` containing your data and some junk data for my testing.

The replacement processing uses `findstr` to see whether the line read (in `%%e`) begins with (`/b`) the literal string (`/L`) constant (`/c:"this string"`), and suppressing the output (`>nul`). This sets `errorlevel` to 0 if found and 1 if not.

If the resultant `errorlevel` is `1` or greater, simply `echo` the line, else (the string was found) so reconstruct the line (including the terminal `;` which appears to have become lost in your narrative)

Note that the construction

```
(
for....do.(
 ....
)
)>filename
```

will recreate `filename` with the contents of (whatever the `for` loop outputs).

Naturally `>>filename` will append this data to an existing file `filename` or create that file if it doesn't already exist